# python for loop adding commas between items

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I want to loop through the list adding commas between items. There has to be an easier way to write this, so that it just pulls out all the tags at once instead of having to loop through over and over.

```
for top_item in items.get_top_tags():
    tag1 = top_item.item.get_name(0)
for top_item in items.get_top_tags(1):
    tag2 = top_item.item.get_name()
for top_item in items.get_top_tags(2):
    tag3 = top_item.item.get_name()
for top_item in items.get_top_tags(3):
    tag4 = top_item.item.get_name()
for top_item in items.get_top_tags(4):
    tag5 = top_item.item.get_name()

tags = (tag1 + ',' + tag2 + ',' + tag3 + ',' + tag4 + ',' + tag5
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `items.get_top_tags()` returns a list with a single item in it? If so, try this:

```
# 'n' is the number of tags you'll be returning, I suppose
', '.join(items.get_top_tags(i)[0].get_name() for i in range(n))
```

Comment: `', '.join(items.get_top_tags(i)[0].get_name() for i in range(n))`

Comment: If get_top_tags doesn't return a list (perhaps it's a generator), you can use next(items.get_top_tags(i)).get_name().

Comment: @Fred: Thanks :) I just wrote it down as I was thinking it in my head. Had to look again, to realize the square brackets were superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly your trying to do in the first bit of your example but I suspect you could replace it with something like:

```
tag_items = items.get_top_tags(4)
```

This would probably give you some kind of collection (e.g. a list or tuple) of tag items.

You could then do a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get a list of just your tag names:

```
tag_names = [tag.item.get_name() for tag in tag_items]
```

Finally you could then turn your list of names into a comma separated string using the  [str.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method.  Below is an example of its use:

```
tags = ','.join([tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like `','.join(yourList)`